# Drop all partitions of a hive table using JAVA SDK

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

I need to drop all the present partitions of a hive table.

I tried searching but all of them where Hive Queries.

my partition pattern is `(year="2018"/month="01")`
Hence trying the expression `year>'0'`

Tried exploring "HiveMetaStoreClient" apis as follows :

```
  public void dropAllPartitions(String hiveDb, String hiveTable) throws MetaException, NoSuchObjectException, TException {

    HiveMetaStoreClient client = new HiveMetaStoreClient(new HiveConf());

    ObjectPair<Integer,byte[]> objectPair =  new ObjectPair<Integer, byte[]>();
    objectPair.setFirst(0);
    String expr = "year>'0'";
    objectPair.setSecond(expr.getBytes());

    List<ObjectPair<Integer,byte[]>> partExprs = new ArrayList<ObjectPair<Integer,byte[]>>();

    partExprs.add(objectPair);

    client.dropPartitions(hiveDb, hiveTable, partExprs, PartitionDropOptions.instance());
  }
```

But i get this error:

```
MetaException(message:Index: 119, Size: 0)
```

I suspected `objectPair.setFirst(0);` might be an issue. 
Debugging deeper i found it is being used by `DropPartitionsExpr.setPartArchiveLevel(partExpr.getFirst())`

But couldn't find any documentation about `setPartArchiveLevel`

Answer (score 0):

The expected byte array is a Kryo serialized `ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc`.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.FieldSchema
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeColumnDesc
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeConstantDesc
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeDesc
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorConverters
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.PrimitiveTypeInfo, 
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.typeinfo.TypeInfoUtils

FieldSchema yearFieldSchema = new FieldSchema("year", "int", "");
String minYear = "2022";

PrimitiveTypeInfo intTypeInfo =
  TypeInfoFactory.getPrimitiveTypeInfo(yearFieldSchema.getType);

ObjectInspectorConverters.Converter converter = ObjectInspectorConverters.getConverter(
    TypeInfoUtils.getStandardJavaObjectInspectorFromTypeInfo(
        TypeInfoFactory.stringTypeInfo
    ),
    TypeInfoUtils.getStandardJavaObjectInspectorFromTypeInfo(
        intTypeInfo
    )
);


ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc expr = new ExprNodeGenericFuncDesc(
    TypeInfoFactory.booleanTypeInfo,
    FunctionRegistry.getFunctionInfo(">").getGenericUDF(),
    Arrays.asList(
        new ExprNodeColumnDesc(intTypeInfo, "year", null, true),
        new ExprNodeConstantDesc(intTypeInfo, converter.convert(partColumnType, minYear))
    )
);

byte[] exprBytes = SerializationUtilities.serializeExpressionToKryo(expr);
```